# Could we define complex hyper operators?

Tags: complex-numbers, tetration, hyperoperation

I made a similar question in the past.

Let's define the function $H_n(a,b)$ to be the $n$-th hyperoperation which imputs are $a$ and $b$.

1. $H_1(a,b)= a+b~~$  Addition
2. $H_2(a,b)= ab~~$  Multiplication
3. $H_3(a,b)= a^b~~$  Exponentiation
4. $H_4(a,b)=$ $^{b}a~~$  Tetration

I already made previous posts trying to extend these to negative integer hyperoperators.

My question here is similar : is there a way to define or calculate something like $H_i(a,b)$ where $i^2=-1$ ? The $i$-th hyperoperation.

And ideally, is there by any chance any ways to calculate the specific number $H_i(i,i)$?

$H_1(i,i)=2i$
$H_2(i,i)=-1$
$H_3(i,i)=e^{-\pi/2}≈0.2078795764$
$H_4(i,i)≈0.50012906+0.32426694i$
$H_5(i,i)=?$
$$H_i(i,i)=?$$

Comment: Even exponentiation is problematic in the complex numbers. The main idea of tetration was to generate huge numbers. Tetration only really makes sense if $b$ is a positive integer. However , $a$ can of course be a real number. A famous open problem is whether $\pi \uparrow \uparrow 4$ is an integer.